# DataTable Cell Values

Tags: c#, datatables, cells

I have three `DataTable`s: `GW_DEFAULT`, `GW_DB` and `GW_DB`.

```
protected void GW_DEFAULT_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{ 
    dtDefault.Text = GW_DEFAULT.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
}

protected void GW_DB_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
   dtDBForm.Text = GW_DB.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
   dtDBField.Text = GW_DB.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
   dtDBDescricao.Text = GW_DB.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
}
```

But instead of going for a `TextBox` I need to go to another `DataTable` and I can define in which column this value will be placed.

The datatables looks like this:

**`GW_DEFAULT`**
   `A1 | B1`

**`GW_DB`**
   `A2 | B2 | C2`

`GW_MAP` will have to return something to this aspect : 
  A2 | B2 | A1 | C2

The number of rows can also be different!

Basically I just need to link that exists in GW_DEFAULT and GW_DB and put in GW_MAP

Comment: Doesn't this work ? - `GW_MAP.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text = GW_DEFAULT.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;`

Comment: I had tried this way gives me this error

The Index was out of range . It must NOT be negative and below the Collection * Size.

Comment: That means GW_MAP doesn't have the same number of rows as GW_DEFAULT. 

You could debug and check GW_MAP.Rows to see if there are any rows at all.

Comment: GW_DEFAULT has 2 columns. GW_MAP will have 4 columns , will inherit one GW_DEFAULT value and inherit three values ​​of another DataTable

Comment: The error you got refers to the rows and not columns. `e.NewSelectedIndex` will be the index of the row from `GW_DEFAULT`. When you try to access `GW_MAP` with the same index, and if you get an error like `"It must NOT be negative and below the Collection * Size."` , it means, `GW_MAP` doesn't have that row index. So I would advice you to check the number of rows in `GW_MAP` at run time.

Comment: I've edited the post. You see what I want .
How can I check the number of rows

Comment: Are you sure GW_MAP is initialized properly and that it has rows when you are attempting to do this? Does GW_DEFAULT and GW_DB always have one row or do they have more than one rows? If they have more than one rows, how do you identify the corresponding row in GW_MAP for a pair of rows in the first two tables? For example, lets say "A2 | B2 | C2" is the 7th row in GW_DB  and "A1 | B1" is the 4th row in GW_DEFAULT. How do you decide where to place the resulting combination "A2 | B2 | A1 | C2" into GW_MAP? Which row should it go to? Your code should be written based on this logic.

Comment: I created array to store the text and the position and then you can put in another datatable in the position I want